# Need to fetch HTML after submitting a form on a website- Android Java/Kotlin

Tags: android, html, post, retrofit

I'm trying to make an Android app where the user writes his name and email...and then clicks submit...Then my app makes a call to the website and gets a response. But the problem is Website doesn't have any public API and the way to get data is to go there website...fill out the form and click submit. The form is using the post method so I can't make a URL with attributes and call it. So, how can I do it now? Please guide me. Do I have to use retrofit for it? If yes then how can add the data which online form is sending using post method

Answer (score 0):

this seems like backend stuff to me. i use Laravel ( a PHP framework) to manage those requests